# Server Blocks in nginx - 502 Error

Tags: nginx, subdomain

I have 2 subdomains I want to catch and forward from one server running nginx:  foo.acme.com, bar.acme.com

In my nginx.conf file I have set up 2 server blocks:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name foo.acme.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://<my_ip_server_1>:80;
    }
}
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name bar.acme.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://<my_ip_server_2>:80;
    }
}
```

My 2 subdomains point to the same IP (the one with nginx running on it).
I'm getting 502 Bad Gateway errors on both servers in this configuration.

Comment: What's in the error log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 502 code means *502 Bad Gateway, The server was acting as a gateway or proxy and received an invalid response from the upstream server.*

It usually means the backend servers are not reachable, which could be a problem with them, not with your front-end configuration.

On the machine running Nginx, you should test that you can rest the backend servers. Using `w3m` or another HTTP client on that machine, check these URLs. Do they load what you expect?

```
http://<my_ip_server_1>:80
http://<my_ip_server_2>:80
```

If not, you may have some updates to make sure that your Nginx server can reach the backend servers.

I should add, you may need send the `Host:` header to get the backend servers to serve the expected content, if they each host multiple virtual domains. I like to use `GET` and `HEAD` tools from the `libwww-perl` distribution:

```
GET -H 'Host: bar.acme.com' http://http://<my_ip_server_1>:80
```

It's important to run the test from the machine hosting Nginx, as running it from your desktop could produce a different result.