# nginx to configure 2 apps in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx

I have 2 apps that use node.js. And below is my nginx config for first site.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

}
```

It's working correctly. Imagine I want to add another app, what should my config be? Do I have to create a new port? like

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name subdomain.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

}
```

Tried the config above, but didn't work for my subdomain, it says `bad gateway`.

Comment: Are both node servers running?  Can I infer that when you say `doesn't work for my subdomain` that the main domain is working?

Comment: @miah yes. the first block is configured properly.

Comment: Sorry to ask again, but you are sure that there is a separate instance of node running on :3001, and is 3001 open/exposed?

Comment: @MariaJane what's the `status code` of `bad gateway` is it a `502`?, if so please make sure your nodeapp is working and reachable at given `port`
refer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/18233838/1254813